# Why ROW_NUMBER is defined as window function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I would like to understand better the meaning of window function. The definition says:

> A window function performs a calculation across a set of table rows (the window) that are somehow related to the current row

Let's consider `ROW_NUMBER()` (the same could be applied for `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`). The function simply assign a number to an ordered set of rows. This seems not to follow the above definition: it's not making a calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow related to the current row, but it's making a calculation across all result rows.

Can someone please explain that?

Comment: A window function is any function that uses the `over` keyword.  Hence, `row_number()` is a window function.

Comment: That appears to be the Postgres docs you're quoting, but you've tagged sql-server

Comment: Do you only use the `ORDER BY` clause? Have you never noticed the `PARTITION BY` option?

Comment: In SQL-Server the subset of window functions you are referring to are called [ranking function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and since they return a value "for each row in a partition", they are also window functions.

Comment: Why can't "the window" be "the whole table"? (Also note that `ROW_NUMBER()` isn't often used across the whole table. That it _can be_ doesn't make it not a window function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the ranking functions fulfill that definition.

When used without a `partition by`, the entire table is the "set of table rows".

The relation to the current row is the value in the current row relative to the other rows.

It follows the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This function adds a virtual sequence number to the rows. Depending on the
PARTITION BY and ORDER BY Window result, this sequence can be restarted multiple
times for the particular window. I mention “virtual” because the row numbers only exist while querying not physically.